# Как подключить node.js сервер к сети Tor с доступом по onion ссылкам?

Tags: node.js, express, tor, onion

На **VPS** установлен **Tor** и сгенерированы скрытые ресурсы с доступом по **.onion**.
На одном *onion*-ресурсе развернут сервер *(backend)* на **Node**/**Express**.
На другом *onion*-ресурсе расположен веб-интерфейс *(frontend)*, который предполагается соединить с сервером по **API**.
-
Посоветуйте, как лучше всего подключить *node*-сервер к сети **Tor** *(принимать запросы из сети)*, чтобы можно было обращаться к нему через сеть **Tor** по "луковым" ссылкам, а не по **ip**?

Comment: Живые есть? Такой сложный вопрос?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/512318/ На сколько понял, то используется обычный веб-сервер, на который проксируются запросы с тор. Соответственно в качестве веб-сервера можно использовать ноду и все что угодно.